# AS3 Add movieclip trough function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, constructor, adobe, typeerror

Is it possible in AS3 to create an 'API' to add movieclips/bitmaps? I tried doing this:

```
public function addImage(name:String, x:int, y:int, type:String = "MovieClip", path:String = null) {
    var mc:MovieClip;

    if (type == "MovieClip") {
        var $name = "as_" + name + "()"
        mc = new $name;
        trace(mc);
    }
    else if (type == "Bitmap") {

    }
}
```

But it errors with:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non constructor
```

Is there a correct way of doing this? Or is it not possible to add movieclips to a stage this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$name` is an instance of a `String`. What you need in order to instantiate an object is a reference to a `Class` which you can get by passing in the class name to `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName`.

Try this:

```
var className:String = "as_" + name;
var MyClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
mc = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! And I do the same for adding a Bitmap I assume?

Comment: Yes, the `getDefinitionByName` method returns a reference of a class by it's name no matter what type it is.